# Is Adlcopy command azure authentication possible through certificates rather from Azure login page?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-authentication

I'm trying to copy files on Azure data lake from one folder to other using adlcopy command. When ever I hit the command, it is opening azure login page for authentication. Is it possible to make this authentication through certificate?

Comment: @Walter-MSFT I'm using Adlcopy tool which I have installed on the machine. When hit the command, it is prompting to enter the credentials for the Azure subscription under which Data Lake Store account is present, Same was mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-copy-data-azure-storage-blob

Answer (score 0):

Adlcopy only supports user AAD identities. User identities could have multi-factor authentication enabled. Service Principal Identity *cannot* be used with AdlCopy. If you would like that sipport, please provide feedback here - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake

Thanks,
Sachin Sheth
Program Manager
Azure Data Lake.